# What does this even mean SUM(sessions.MIN(transactions.amount)) from the official featuretools documentation?

Tags: python, featuretools

Can someone help me with how such a feature created automatically by Deep Feature Synthesis will actually work? I came across so many such features created and I'm not sure of how it works. I am unable to hook up the whole code here, although  I am sure people who read through the official featuretools document are aware of this example. Hoping to see a response! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature generated for the “customers” table.

The feature `SUM(sessions.MIN(transactions.amount))` can be interpreted as the sum of the minimum transaction amount from each session for a customer.

This is calculated by

- Finding all the sessions for a customer
- Calculating the minimum transaction amount for each session
- Summing that minimum amount across all sessions for a customer

Featuretools uses Deep Feature Synthesis to stack primitives to make more complex features. So in this case, it used the `MIN` primitive and `SUM` primitive to generate a feature with a depth of 2. This depth is useful because you get complex patterns for machine learning.

For example, the feature `MAX(sessions.SUM(transactions.amount))` can be interpreted as the maximum amount a customer spent across all sessions.

Comment: When you said **This is a feature generated for the “customers” table.**, did you mean that feature will be generated based on the unique customer_id, which is essentially a table with 5 rows in this case with the rows uniquely identified by the unique customer_id? Furthermore, if I want to generate a feature FOR a table, then I must put that ytable name in target_variable, right?

Comment: Thanks Max, your reply did help me understand a lot in fearuretools which I am possibly trying to use in my college project, hope everything goes well!

thanks and regards
Dan